# Keras ValueError: Dimensions must be equal

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

The goal of the model is to categorically classify video inputs by the word articulated with them. Each input has the dimensionality 45 frames, 1 gray color channel, 100 pixel rows, and 150 pixel columns (45, 1, 100, 150), while each corresponding output is a one hot encoded representation of one of 3 possible words (e.g. "yes" => [0, 0, 1]).

During the compilation of the model, the following error occurs:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 3 for 'Conv2D_94' (op: 'Conv2D') with 
input shapes: [?,100,150,1], [3,3,3,32].
```

Here is the script used to train the model:

```
video = Input(shape=(self.frames_per_sequence,
                     1,
                     self.rows,
                     self.columns))
cnn = InceptionV3(weights="imagenet",
                  include_top=False)
cnn.trainable = False
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
encoded_vid = LSTM(256)(encoded_frames)
hidden_layer = Dense(output_dim=1024, activation="relu")(encoded_vid)
outputs = Dense(output_dim=class_count, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer)
osr = Model([video], outputs)
optimizer = Nadam(lr=0.002,
                  beta_1=0.9,
                  beta_2=0.999,
                  epsilon=1e-08,
                  schedule_decay=0.004)
osr.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
```

Comment: @roganjosh please see the updated question. Thank you.

Comment: @roganjosh you said remove the traceback so I did.

Comment: You misread that comment. I meant "post the traceback properly formatted instead of an image". I can't think of any situation in which removing the traceack could help. It just shouldn't be a cropped image. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @roganjosh gotcha. I have updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Convolution2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d) in Keras, the following should be the shape of input and filter.

```
shape of input = [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]
shape of filter = [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]
```

So, the meaning of the error you are getting -

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 3 for 'Conv2D_94' (op: 'Conv2D') with 
input shapes: [?,100,150,1], [3,3,3,32].
```

`[?,100,150,1]` means `in_channels` value is 1 whereas `[3,3,3,32]` means `in_channels` value is 3. Thats why you are getting the error - `Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 3`.

So you can change the shape of the filter to `[3, 3, 1, 32]`.