# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1024 and 256 for

Tags: keras, deep-learning, seq2seq

I am trying to use Keras seq2seq model but kept having an error.

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1024 and 256 for '{{node mul}}
= Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](Sigmoid_1, init_c)' with input shapes: [?,13,1024], [?,256].

```
#encoder input data shape (592, 58)

#decoder input data shape (592, 52, 9)

#decoder output data shape (592, 51*9)

encoder_inputs= keras.Input(shape=(None,592))
encoder_lstm= keras.layers.LSTM(units=256, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h,state_c=encoder_lstm(encoder_inputs)
encoder_states= [state_h,state_c]
decoder_inputs= keras.Input(shape=(None,52,9))
decoder_lstm= keras.layers.LSTM(units=256, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs,_,_= decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_softmax_layer= Dense(51*9,activation='relu')
decoder_outputs= decoder_softmax_layer(decoder_outputs)
model= Model([encoder_inputs,decoder_inputs],decoder_outputs)
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="msle")
model.summary()
model.fit(x=[all_seqtf,all_anitf],y=all_ani2tf, batch_size=64, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried this [Solution]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497925/keras-valueerror-dimensions-must-be-equal

Comment: Yes! I actually saw it, but I do not know how to adjust this solution. How could I change the filter value with seq2seq model?